# How to implement compareTo for any types of comparable objects

Tags: java, object, interface, comparable, compareto

I don’t know how I can compare 2 comparable objects without some other variable which tells me which is larger. The question is: Create a class called Max that provides a single class method called max. max takes two arguments to objects that can be compared—that is, that implement the Java Comparable interface as shown above. It returns a reference to whichever is larger. If the two objects are equal, you should return the first. How Comparable is implemented is up to each class, and your method will be called on multiple different kinds of objects.

It gives the int compareTo (Object other) method in the interface but I’m having trouble finding a solution.

```
public class Max implements Comparable 
{
    public int compareTo(Object other)
    {

    }

    public static Comparable max(Comparable first, Comparable second)
    {
        int fi = first.compareTo(second);
        if(fi >0)
            return first;
        else if (fi<0)
            return second;
        return first; 
    }
}
```

> java.lang.AssertionError: Class should not implement Comparable: expected [false] but found [true]

That is one of the errors. But also I need help writing the compareTo method.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear:  The `Max` class should not implement Comparable.

Comment: Expected false but found true? Also if you don’t implement it gives the same error

Answer (score 0):

I deleted my previous answer because I think, imho, you are over complicating this.  Since the two arguments to `max` have implemented the `Comparable<T>` interface, all you have to do is call it as:

```java
int ret = first.compareTo(second);
```

Then return first or second like you are doing based on the value of `ret`.  That way you don't need to know anything about how it was implemented.  Perhaps you could get some clarification from either your instructor or someone else who is working on this (I presume it is for an assignment).

It would be worthwhile for you to create some test classes which implement the interface.  You can just make up some variable that represents size.

Comment: What is foo.size and how does that give the size of a given max if it wasn’t assigned anything

Comment: See my new answer.  Imho, `max` is just one way of expressing which one is `larger`.  That is how `Comparable<T>` works.  It returns `1 for larger, -1 for smaller, and 0 for equals`.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword for your question is generics. You might want to do some research and read something about it. Take a look at the following example. I've implemented the class Max as a static class to keep it simple:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class MyTestClass{ 
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Integer i = 16;
        Integer j = 15;
        Integer m = Max.max(i, j);
        System.out.println(m);
        String k = "aaaa";
        String n = "zzzz";
        String s = Max.max(k, n);
        System.out.println(s);
        LocalDate d = LocalDate.now();
        LocalDate e = LocalDate.now().plusDays(2);
        LocalDate f = Max.max(d , e);
        System.out.println(f);
    }
    static class Max{
        public static <T extends Comparable> T max(T first, T second) {            
            if (first.compareTo(second) >= 0)
                return first;
            else
                return second;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is a class Max with a single method max which accepts two objects, for example two integers, two strings or two date objects.

Since all these classes implement the comparable interface, you can use the max method for all object types. The compiler then decides during the runtime which comapreTo method to call, that is the compareTo of the class Integer, String, LocalDate or whatever.